# Should [attask] tag be made a synonym of [workfront-api]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Most questions for the Workfront/AtTask API are tagged [attask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attask). This is now invalid as the company has re-branded to Workfront.

> [Started in 2001 as
>   AtTask.....](https://www.workfront.com/about-us/?language=en-gb)

There is a more up to date tag [workfront-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workfront-api). So essentially I think all questions [attask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attask) should be made a synonym of [workfront-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workfront-api). Is a synonym the best thing to do here?

I don't currently have enough rep in this tag to create synonyms.